# how to retrieve and loop records from 2 tables in rails2.3

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a transport table and students and employee table. In the transport table I have a column mem_id and mem_type, vehicle_id, date etc.... I am fetching the records of a vehicle of a date like this..

```
@mem = []
@tran = Transport.find_all_by_month_and_vehicle(date,vehicle)
tran.each do |t|
@mem << Student.find_by_id(t.mem_id) if t.mem_type=="Student"
@mem<< Employee.find_by_id(t.mem_id) if t.mem_type=="Employee"
end
```

Now in the @mem I am getting the records of Students and Employees... But in the view file I am displaying the name, age and id of the students in a table.

```
@mem.each do |m|
<tr>
            <td><%= link_to m.first_name} %></td>
            <td > <%= m.age %></td>
            <td id="date">  </td>
            <td id="vehicle">vehicle no</td>
          </tr>
<%end%>
```

In the `#date` and `#vehicle_no`, I need to display the corresponding records `vehicle_id` and date of Transport table. How will I achieve it? Do I need to join both the tables for that? I am not sure how to do join operation. OR do I need to loop `@tran` and insert it into date and vehicle columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need these two columns, I think you don't need to add additional joins, just add two columns in your array, you have got the transport and vehicle record in the controller.

I assume you have "transport_date" in "transport" model and "no" in "vehicle" model:

```
@mem = []
@tran = Transport.find_all_by_month_and_vehicle(date,vehicle)
tran.each do |t|
  @mem << [Student.find_by_id(t.mem_id), t.transport_date, vehicle.no] if t.mem_type=="Student"
  @mem << [Employee.find_by_id(t.mem_id), t.transport_date, vehicle.no] if t.mem_type=="Employee"
end
```

and change your view:

```
@mem.each do |m|
  <tr>
            <td><%= link_to m[0].first_name} %></td>
            <td > <%= m[0].age %></td>
            <td id="date"> m[1] </td>
            <td id="vehicle"> m[2] </td>
  </tr>
<%end%>
```

I just show you an easy way to do this, and I think your codes can be optimized further.

Comment: Thanks.. It worked.!.. I guess the above code can be optimized if we use rails associations right?

Comment: I am getting duplicate entries here.. How do I delete the duplicates from this array..

Comment: What is the detail of duplicate entries ?